# StructureMap.Container tries to use removed assembly

Tags: c#, structuremap

I've recently removed one assembly and all of it's references from my solution and replaced it with another one.
When I try to use `StructureMap.Container.Configure()` or `StructureMap.Container(Action<ConfigurationExpression> expression)` constructor 
I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, `Could not load file or assembly 'WebUtilities...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` and `WebUtilities` is an assembly I removed from all projects in solution. I've searched all the files and there are no usings or mentions of this assembly. How does this error occur and why?

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at StructureMap.Graph.TypePool.<.ctor>b__0(Assembly assembly) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Graph\TypePool.cs:line 16
   at StructureMap.Util.LightweightCache`2.get_Item(TKey key) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Util\LightweightCache.cs:line 77
   at StructureMap.Graph.TypePool.<>c__DisplayClass3.<For>b__2(Assembly x) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Graph\TypePool.cs:line 21
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at StructureMap.StringExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Extensions.cs:line 10
   at StructureMap.Graph.AssemblyScanner.ScanForTypes(TypePool types, PluginGraph pluginGraph) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Graph\AssemblyScanner.cs:line 127
   at StructureMap.PluginGraphBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass2.<RunConfigurations>b__1(AssemblyScanner x) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\PluginGraphBuilder.cs:line 82
   at StructureMap.StringExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Extensions.cs:line 12
   at StructureMap.PluginGraphBuilder.RunConfigurations() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\PluginGraphBuilder.cs:line 82
   at StructureMap.PluginGraphBuilder.Build() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\PluginGraphBuilder.cs:line 45
   at StructureMap.ConfigurationExpression.BuildGraph() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\ConfigurationExpression.cs:line 54
   at StructureMap.PipelineGraph.For(Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\PipelineGraph.cs:line 19
   at StructureMap.Container..ctor(Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 25
   at IoC.ObjFactory.GetContainer(Action`1 expression) in d:\development\Projects\commerce\Source Code\Shared\IoC\ObjFactory.cs:line 40
```

This is happening on my local machine, I've already removed all temporary ASP .Net files, restarted Visual Studio and PC several times, manually removed all bin and obj folders from all projects in solution. No project is referencing the assembly.

Comment: Is this happening on your local machine or on a build server? File path looks like a build server so could it possibly be cached?

Comment: @timothyclifford, it's happening on my local machine. All temporary aspnet files are removed.

Comment: What's happening on `d:\development\Projects\commerce\Source Code\Shared\IoC\ObjFactory.cs:line 40`

Comment: What was previously referencing WebUtilities? Is this still referenced somewhere? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? Have you deleted bin and obj folders?

Comment: @timothyclifford line 40: this is the line where I call `Container(Action<ConfigurationExpression> expression)` ctor. WebUtilities was removed and nothing is referencing it. I've restarted VS and PC several times, cleared solution (removed all bin and obj folders).